# Skip certain tabs when cycling through them in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, user-experience

In VSCode, pressing <kbd>ctrl + pgup</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl + pgdn</kbd> cycles backwards and forwards between tabs, respectively.

However I often have multiple editors opened side-by-side. For example one on the left, which I don't want to change; and one on the right with multiple tabs. I want to cycle through the tabs on the right, without affecting the tab(s) on the left.

Is it possible to change the key bindings above, or introduce new ones, to "skip" certain tabs? For example, to cycle tabs in the current editor only, or skip tabs which are somehow marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: <kbd>ctrl+k ctrl+pageup</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+k ctrl+pagedown</kbd>, which correspond to commands `workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup` and `workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup`.

I find those combos to be unusable though, so I remapped them in `keybindings.json`:

```json
{ "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+pagedown", "command": "-workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup" },
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+pagedown",    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditorInGroup" },

{ "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+pageup",   "command": "-workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup" },
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+pageup",      "command": "workbench.action.previousEditorInGroup" },
```